# Angular 14: Getting 'An index signature parameter type must be either 'string' or 'number' error on vs2022 while build the application

Tags: angular, typescript

"Error  TS1023  Build:An index signature parameter type must be either 'string' or 'number'.    \node_modules@angular\router\index.d.ts"

Above is the build error i am facing. In local the application is running perfectly but while we go with CICD pipeline and vs2022 application build it throws angular build error.

In local angular build no error.
[image: local angular build result]

Below is my package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^14.0.1",
    "@angular/cdk": "^14.0.1",
    "@angular/common": "^14.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^14.0.1",
    "@angular/core": "^14.0.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^14.0.1",
    "@angular/material": "^14.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^14.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^14.0.1",
    "@angular/router": "14.0.0",
    "angular2-multiselect-dropdown": "^5.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.1",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^9.0.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "ngx-spinner": "14.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^14.0.1",
    "@angular/cli": "~14.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^14.0.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "typescript": "~4.7.2"
  },
```

This is the error i am facing in vs2022 application
[image: Error that shows in VS2022 application build]

Tried in different type of angular 14 version but same result. Any other suggestions to resolve this?

Comment: Did you  resolve your issue?

Comment: I would not add this as an anwer, but in my case for other project it was because there was a dep with a major typescript version difference, I was on 4, while the dep was on 5, i just downgraded the dep to a version using typescript 4